# Ant Design Vue Select Display Existing Items

Tags: vue.js, antd, antdv

Using Ant Design in Vue. In a Multi-select component, user is able to select and unselect associated objects. However, the existing tokens of preexisting associated objects should show the item.name, but instead show "undefined". It also does not show a checkmark next to existing objects in the select box. However, on submit, the "undefined" object is submitted correctly. New choices display within the select box correctly.[image]

Here is the element in the view:

```html
<a-form-item :label="`${contact.name}'s Outlets`"
                   :wrapperCol="{lg: {span: 20}, sm: {span: 24} }">
        <a-select
            mode="multiple"
            v-model="contact.outlets"
            style="width: 100%"
            placeholder="Please select"
        >
          <a-select-option v-for="outlet in outlets" :key="outlet.name" :value="outlet.id">
            {{ outlet.name }}
          </a-select-option>
        </a-select>
      </a-form-item>
```

Comment: Can you fork this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-ant-design-troubleshooting-initial-select-value?file=src/App.vue) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @tony19 thanks for this, but the issue is with seeing current Outlets for the contact. e.g if I change line 34 in your example to be: const contact = reactive({ name: 'John', outlets: [{id: 4, name: 'Outlet D'}] });, I see the same issue as described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments, you used an object element in `contact.outlets[]` for the initial value of the select. However, the `a-select`'s `value` properties are bound to each element's `id`, so no match is found:

```html
<a-select-option
        v-for="outlet in outlets"
        :key="outlet.name"
        :value="outlet.id"  option value is an `id`
>
```

#### Solution

Instead of the object as initial value, use the object's `id`.

###### Composition API

```js
export default {
  setup() {
    const outlets = reactive([
      { id: 1, name: 'Outlet A' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Outlet B' },
            
      { id: 3, name: 'Outlet C' },
    ]);                                                
    const contact = reactive({ name: 'John', outlets: [3] });

    return { outlets, contact };
  }
}
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-ant-design-initial-select-value?file=src/App.vue)

###### Options API

```js
export default {
  data() {
    const outlets = [
      { id: 1, name: 'Outlet A' },
      { id: 2, name: 'Outlet B' },
            
      { id: 3, name: 'Outlet C' },
    ];                                        
    const contact = { name: 'John', outlets: [3] };

    return { outlets, contact };
  }
}
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue2-ant-design-initial-select-value?file=src%2FApp.vue)